# Setup ASP.Net Core 2.1V in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-express, iis-10

Asp.net core 2.1v web application hosted in IIS 10v,

after hosting the application on server, I cant reach the URL.

I did followed link to setup as per my version.

appreciated your response.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean that cannot  reach the URL? You just need to bind the appliation to hostname and port, then enter the http://hostname:port in bowser to access it. Do you have any error message or log? Additionally, do you install [AspNetCoreModuleV2](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-2.2.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer) in IIS?

Comment: There could be a multitude of reasons. Adding some more information like screenshots of your iis binding properties/config, site logs, etc will help. this is too little information to go on.